# LEFT JOIN with WHERE on right table, doctrine2 on oneToMany

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, left-join

I found some posts here but it still doesn't work:

I have 2 Entities Story and StoryCompleted:

```
TA\Minigames\MinigameBundle\Entity\Story:
    type: entity
    table: story
    id:
        id:
            type: integer
            generator: { strategy: AUTO }
    oneToMany:
        completed:
            targetEntity: StoryCompleted
            mappedBy: story
    fields:
        cycle_nr: 
            type: integer

TA\Minigames\MinigameBundle\Entity\StoryCompleted:
    type: entity
    table: story_completed
    id:
        id:
            type: integer
            generator: { strategy: AUTO }
    manyToOne:
        story:
            targetEntity: Story
    fields:
        company_id: 
            type: integer
        completed:
            type: boolean
```

I would like to get a list of all stories and know which stories are seen by company_id = 1, so I tried a Left Join:

```
SELECT s FROM MGMinigameBundle:Story s LEFT JOIN s.completed c WHERE s.cycle_nr = 1 AND (c.company_id = $company_id OR c is NULL)
```

And I wold like to get for a $company_id something like this:

```
story_id completed
1         1
2         -
3         -
```

But I get, in each Story, all completed Entities(for all $company_id) and not just one, for a given $company_id and have to Iterate over them to find the one I need. :(

Answer (score 1):

Include "c" in your select statement:

```
SELECT s, c 
FROM MGMinigameBundle:Story s 
LEFT JOIN s.completed c 
WHERE s.cycle_nr = 1 AND (c.company_id = $company_id OR c is NULL)
```

This way the StoryCompleted records will be used to "hydrate" the Story object's completed collection based on the company_id. This is the difference between a ["regular join" and a "fetch join" in DQL](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#joins)